# Module object has no attribute 'VideoCapture'

Tags: python, opencv, video

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('drop.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while cv2.VideoCaptured('drop.avi') is True:
    # Captures frame x frame
    ret , frame = cap.read()
    #Frame operations
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    name = "frame%d.jpg"%count #saves frames and a JPEG image file
    cv2.imwrite(name, frame)

    #Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(30):`enter code here`
    break

    cv.VideoCapture.release()
```

When I want the code to strictly read the video form the file and not from my webcam. I am aware that I need to delete the `cap = cv2.VideoCpature(0)`. However, I get the error `'module' object has no attribute 'VideoCapture'`. This code was from an official OpenCV tutorial so I am not sure what is the problem. My guess is that something is not in the correct folder.

Answer (score 3):

The correct code snippet to read in a video is:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(PATH_VIDEO)
cap.open(PATH_VIDEO)
print cap.isOpened()
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (frame.shape[1]/3, frame.shape[0]/3))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What code am I to keep and delete?                               import numpy as np
import cv2
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
PATH_VIDEO = cv2.VideoWriter('drop.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(PATH_VIDEO)
capture.open(PATH_VIDEO)
print capture.isOpened()
while(capture.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (frame.shape[1]/3, frame.shape[0]/3))         This is what I have now